# this in event handling functions of Meteor: How does this get bound to model object?

Tags: javascript, meteor

The following code is taken from a [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/whats-this-meteor-thing/) in tutsplus.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    var Products = new Array(
        {   Name: "Screw Driver",
            Price: "1.50",
            InStock: true},
        {   Name: "Hammer",
            Price: "2.50",
            InStock: false}
    );
    Template.Products.ProductArr = function () {
        return Products;
    };
    Template.Products.events = {
        "click .Product": function () {
            if (this.InStock)
                confirm("Would you like to buy a " + this.Name + " for " + this.Price + "$");
            else
                alert("That item is not in stock");
        }
    };
}
```

Here is the template:

```
<template name="Products">
  {{#each ProductArr}}
  <div class="Product">
    <h2>{{Name}}</h2>
    <p>Price: ${{Price}}</p>
    {{#if this.InStock}}
      <p>This is in stock</p>
    {{else}}
      <p>This is sold out</p>
    {{/if}}
  </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

I wonder how `this` get bound to the model object product? This looks like magic to me.

The expression `"click .Product"` specifies that the `click` event on HTML elements having class `Product` should trigger the specified function. I understand it. But I don't understand why `this` is bound to an element of the `Products` array.

Answer (score 1):

This is how Handlebars (which Meteor builds on) works. What you're seeing in the template isn't pure JS, but syntax specific to Handlebars.

Inside the *each* block helper, the context is to set each element of the array you're iterating over. So if you use *InStock*, it will look for it on the element of the current iteration.

The **this** keyword is used for disambiguation. This comes in handy if you have a general helper registered with the name *InStock*, like this, for example:

```
Template.Products.InStock = function (){
   //...
};
```

But you want to make sure you're referring to the property of the element from the array, so you can use **this** to access its context explicitly.

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure you were referring to the **this** used in the template, or in the event handler...